# Using glDrawElements does not draw my .obj file

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to correctly import an .OBJ file from 3ds Max. I got this working using glBegin() & glEnd() from a previous question on here, but had really poor performance obviously, so I am trying to use glDrawElements now.

I am importing a chessboard, its game pieces, etc. The board, each game piece, and each square on the board is stored in a struct `GroupObject`. The way I store the data is like this:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float position[3];
    float texCoord[2];
    float normal[3];
    float tangent[4];
    float bitangent[3];
};

struct Material
{
    float ambient[4];
    float diffuse[4];
    float specular[4];
    float shininess;        // [0 = min shininess, 1 = max shininess]
    float alpha;            // [0 = fully transparent, 1 = fully opaque]

    std::string name;
    std::string colorMapFilename;
    std::string bumpMapFilename;

   std::vector<int> indices;
   int id;
  };

 //A chess piece or square
 struct GroupObject
 {
     std::vector<Material *> materials;
     std::string    objectName;
     std::string    groupName;
     int      index;
 };
```

All vertices are triangles, so there are always 3 points. When I am looping through the faces `f` section in the obj file, I store the v0, v1, & v2 in the Material->indices. (I am doing v[0-2] - 1 to account for obj files being 1-based and my vectors being 0-based.

So when I get to the render method, I am trying to loop through every object, which loops through every material attached to that object. I set the material information and try and use glDrawElements. However, the screen is black. I was able to draw the model just fine when I looped through each distinct material with all the indices associated with that material, and it drew the model fine. This time around, so I can use the stencil buffer for selecting `GroupObject`s, I changed up the loop, but the screen is black.

**UPDATE** 
Replaced original render loop with current one and screenshot of it's result
Here is my render loop. The only thing I changed was the for loop(s) so they go through each object, and each material in the object in turn.

```
void GLEngine::drawModel()
{
ModelTextures::const_iterator iter;
GLuint texture = 0;

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// Vertex arrays setup
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, model.getVertexSize(), model.getVertexBuffer()->position);

glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, model.getVertexSize(), model.getVertexBuffer()->normal);

glClientActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, model.getVertexSize(), model.getVertexBuffer()->texCoord);

glUseProgram(blinnPhongShader);

objects = model.getObjects();
// Loop through objects...
for( int i=0 ; i < objects.size(); ++i ) 
{
    ModelOBJ::GroupObject *object = objects[i];

    // Loop through materials used by object...
    for( int j=0 ; j<object->materials.size() ; ++j ) 
    {
        ModelOBJ::Material *pMaterial = object->materials[j];

        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, pMaterial->ambient);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, pMaterial->diffuse);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, pMaterial->specular);
        glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, pMaterial->shininess * 128.0f);

        if (pMaterial->bumpMapFilename.empty())
        {

             //Bind the color map texture.
            texture = nullTexture;
            if (enableTextures)
            {
                iter = modelTextures.find(pMaterial->colorMapFilename);

                if (iter != modelTextures.end())
                    texture = iter->second;
            }

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

             //Update shader parameters.
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(
                blinnPhongShader, "colorMap"), 0);
            glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(
                blinnPhongShader, "materialAlpha"), pMaterial->alpha);
        }
        //glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, pMaterial->triangleCount * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &pMaterial->indices.front() );
        glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, pMaterial->triangleCount * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, model.getIndexBuffer() + pMaterial->startIndex );

    }

}
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glUseProgram(0);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Here is what the above method draws:
http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/3793/chess4.png

I don't know what I am missing that's important. If it's also helpful, here is where I read a 'f' face line and store the info in the obj importer in the pMaterial->indices.

```
 else if (sscanf(buffer, "%d/%d/%d", &v[0], &vt[0], &vn[0]) == 3) // v/vt/vn
        {
            fscanf(pFile, "%d/%d/%d", &v[1], &vt[1], &vn[1]);
            fscanf(pFile, "%d/%d/%d", &v[2], &vt[2], &vn[2]);

            v[0] = (v[0] < 0) ? v[0] + numVertices - 1 : v[0] - 1;
            v[1] = (v[1] < 0) ? v[1] + numVertices - 1 : v[1] - 1;
            v[2] = (v[2] < 0) ? v[2] + numVertices - 1 : v[2] - 1;

currentMaterial->indices.push_back(v[0]);
currentMaterial->indices.push_back(v[1]);
currentMaterial->indices.push_back(v[2]);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Current output: http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/860/chess4s.png

Comment: Well, definitely one problem is that you should be doing glDrawElements like you have in your last quote. Or maybe better, &pMaterial->indices.front(). I've been looking at this for a while now, thinking I'd found other problems, but I still haven't really figured anything else out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with your suggestion also, and still nothing drawn. Just the black background. I am to the point where I am willing to post the entire source code somewhere because I know it's gotta be something simple. I think I have just been looking at it too long

Comment: Added an update to the end of my post

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps it is drawing, but it's drawing black over top of what you did draw, due to a problem with the materials or textures? Speaking of textures, I don't see you binding a texture, which could very well be the problem! Also, you check whether you should disable things at the bottom, but they're enabled at the top without checking.

Comment: Getting closer, Adding a texture drew the bottom of the board and an 'L' shaped strip. I disable at the end like this: glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glUseProgram(0);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems to me you don't need the *3 on the DrawElements line. Because you're not just drawing vertices, you're drawing from all the arrays, and when you specified each one you told it how many is an "element". EDIT: Oh, and what I meant about the enabling/disabling was the glEnableClientState things; you were enabling all of them at the top, but not necessarily disabling all of them at the bottom (really you should check in both places).

Comment: Oddly enough, when I change it to `glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, pMaterial->triangleCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, model.getIndexBuffer() + pMaterial->startIndex );` without the * 3, it still looks the same. I may take the time to check this into github later today.

Comment: I guess it just meant you were drawing a bunch of stuff twice, which didn't look any different.

Comment: If you want to take a closer look, the whole project is available here. I included the proper libraries & SDL file, so if you have Visual Studio, it should compile on loading solution. https://github.com/nbyloff/KinectChess

Comment: I would agree that it seems like the problem is not in the drawing method now. I cloned the git repository, but I haven't compiled it because I'm on Mac and I didn't want to start up my VM to run Windows (it uses a lot of ram).

Comment: This is where I stand now with the code currently checked in. http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/860/chess4s.png I believe the fix is within buildMeshes() in the ModelOBJ file. I am creating a buildObjects() method to try and duplicate its efforts.

Comment: I am wondering if its a problem using the same material in more than one place. For instance. Say object1 has 4 materials under it. but there is TRULY only two distinct materials. The array alternates like Material1, Material2, Material1, Material2. BUT each of the 4 Materials listed under that object have distinct indices. I loaded the objects and their nested materials the way they were in the OBJ file. And in some cases, the OBJ file alternated back and forth between materials with different vertices. That should work I would think, and the fact I am making progress indicates it should?

Comment: Regardless. I am going to finish making the buildObjects based on what buildMeshes is trying to do in the code I checked in. It was something I overlooked earlier, and when I made modifications to the startIndex * 3, things started looking better. Which led me to believe that section of code is the source of the problem.

Comment: Well, I probably can't be of any more help; I haven't even done anything 3D with OpenGL, or anything with materials. Good luck though!

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted you every time for your valiant effort regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the model with the following code

```
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, pMaterial->triangleCount * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, model.getIndexBuffer() + pMaterial->startIndex );
```

When I was done importing the model, I went through running a triangleCount & set the startIndex like so. This was my solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(m_attributeBuffer.size()); i++)
{
    if (m_attributeBuffer[i] != materialId)
    {
        materialId = m_attributeBuffer[i];
        ++numMaterials;
    }
}

// Allocate memory for the materials and reset counters.
m_numberOfObjectMaterials = numMaterials;
m_materials.resize(m_numberOfObjectMaterials);
numMaterials = 0;
materialId = -1;

// Build the meshes. One mesh for each unique material.
for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(m_attributeBuffer.size()); i++)
{
    if (m_attributeBuffer[i] != materialId)
    {
        materialId = m_attributeBuffer[i];
        m = m_ObjectMaterials[materialId];
        m->startIndex = i * 3;
        m->triangleCount = 0;
        ++m->triangleCount;
    }
    else
    {
        ++m->triangleCount;
    }
}
```